# Где найти годную инфу про «автоматическое управление версиями» файлов JS,CSS для PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, css

Вопрос, собственно, в этом и заключается: где найти годную инфу про "автоматическое управление версиями" файлов JS,CSS для PHP?

Проблема состоит в том, что браузер кэширует JS,CSS файлы , а при их изменении на ПК и загрузке на сервер они не изменяются, т.к. уже как бы лежат в кэше.
Я бы мог вручную в php файлах дописывать что-то типа "./js/my_script.js?version=12345" , но хочется какого-то автоматического решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте функцию `filemtime`, она возвращает время последнего изменения указанного файла. Время возвращается в формате временной метки Unix.

```php
<script src="/js/my_script.js?version=<?php echo filemtime( '/js/my_script.js' ); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю, это то, что я искал